# How to find out the driver node for my Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, port, driver, hadoop-yarn

My spark Job is submmited by oozie in hue. The spark is running in yarn-cluster mode. I am trying to monitor the running application status by so-called driver's 4040 port, but I cannot find the 4040 port, I check the process:

```
appuser 137872 137870 0 18:55 ? 00:00:00 /bin/bash -c /home/jdk/bin/java -server -Xmx4096m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data6/data/hadoop/tmp/usercache/appuser/appcache/application_1493800575189_0547/container_1493800575189_0547_01_000004/tmp '-Dspark.driver.port=36503' '-Dspark.ui.port=0' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/home/log/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1493800575189_0547/container_1493800575189_0547_01_000004 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.120.117.107:36503 --executor-id 3 --hostname 10.120.117.100 --cores 1 --app-id application_1493800575189_0547 --user-class-path file:/data6/data/hadoop/tmp/usercache/appuser/appcache/application_1493800575189_0547/container_1493800575189_0547_01_000004/__app__.jar 1> /home/log/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1493800575189_0547/container_1493800575189_0547_01_000004/stdout 2> /home/log/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1493800575189_0547/container_1493800575189_0547_01_000004/stderr
appuser 138337 137872 99 18:55 ? 00:05:11 /home/jdk/bin/java -server -Xmx4096m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data6/data/hadoop/tmp/usercache/appuser/appcache/application_1493800575189_0547/container_1493800575189_0547_01_000004/tmp -Dspark.driver.port=36503 -Dspark.ui.port=0 -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/home/log/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1493800575189_0547/container_1493800575189_0547_01_000004 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill %p org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.120.117.107:36503 --executor-id 3 --hostname 10.120.117.100 --cores 1 --app-id application_1493800575189_0547 --user-class-path file:/data6/data/hadoop/tmp/usercache/appuser/appcache/application_1493800575189_0547/container_1493800575189_0547_01_000004/__app__.jar
```

I don't know why the spark.ui.port is 0 instead of 4040. Of course , the port 0 is not allowed by my linux system.So , I cannot monitor the application status from REST api.

Anybody can give me some suggestions?

---

Great thanks for the answer from Mariusz, is the below a spark ApplicationMaster process?

```
[appuser@hz-10-120-117-100 bin]$ ps -ef|grep ApplicationMaster
appuser  125805 125803  0 May03 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash -c /home/jdk/bin/java -server -Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data6/data/hadoop/tmp/usercache/appuser/appcache/application_1493800575189_0014/container_1493800575189_0014_01_000001/tmp -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/home/log/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1493800575189_0014/container_1493800575189_0014_01_000001 org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster --class 'com.netease.ecom.data.gjs.statis.online.app.day.AppDayRealtimeStatis' --jar hdfs://datahdfsmaster/user/appuser/bjmazhengbing/jar/spark_streaming/spark-streaming-etl-2.0.jar --arg 'analysis_gjs_online.properties' --arg 'rrr' --properties-file /data6/data/hadoop/tmp/usercache/appuser/appcache/application_1493800575189_0014/container_1493800575189_0014_01_000001/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties 1> /home/log/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1493800575189_0014/container_1493800575189_0014_01_000001/stdout 2> /home/log/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1493800575189_0014/container_1493800575189_0014_01_000001/stderr
```

According to the official document of Spark, the driver program should have a 4040 port which is used for monitoring, but my driver program seems didn't open any port:

```
[appuser@hz-10-120-117-100 bin]$ netstat -ntlp|grep 125805
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
```

What I finally purpose of finding out the driver port is to monitor the application status. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

The process you listed is an executor, not a driver.

When you run application in `yarn-cluster` mode, spark driver and yarn application master run in the same JVM. So the easiest way to determine Spark UI address is to go to recource manager's UI, find your application and click a link to Application Master. This will be a proxy adress, pointing to driver's ui port.

Comment: Great thanks for your help.I have edited my port.Would you please give me more suggestions?

Comment: You don't need to log to hadoop nodes to determine port. The easiest way is to use Resource Manager UI (as I described above), but if you preffer CLI you can use yarn command: `$ yarn application -status application_1493800575189_0014`.  This will show you tracking URL for spark driver.

Comment: Great Job!   `yarn application -status application_1493800575189_0014`  provides very useful information.Thank you very much.